# Is the default kmer 25 value in Trinity still ok for assembly of 150bp reads from Illumina HiSeq 2500?

Tags: rna-sequencing, sequence-analysis, sequence-assembly

I will soon be receiving Illumina HiSeq 2500 data (150bp PE stranded reads). In the past we have been using Trinity as our assembler of choice, but it uses a default kmer value of 25. I believe this may have been optimal for GAIIx data (35bp) but is it still ok to use such a kmer for 150bp data?

All inputs will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: what sequencing are you doing- WGS/RNAseq/... ?

Comment: I am doing RNA-seq of multiplexed samples in order to determine differential expression between different samples

Comment: I have't used trinity.. I use cufflinks and for longer reads (>50nt) this is not really necessary (by default off in cufflinks for reads >50nt)..

Comment: As far as I know, Tophat-cufflinks require a reference, don't they? I am working on a non-model organism so will be doing de novo assembly, hence the use of Trinity. What do you mean is not necessary?

Comment: Oh okay.. In that case I cant say. I have some acquaintance with velvet but not trinity. In tophat (I am sorry I said cufflinks) that is used for enhanced prediction for splice junctions. 
For de-novo assembly the choice of k-mers should be such that it maximizes your N50 but does't consume a lot of resources. You can see [this](http://seqanswers.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2252) post

Comment: Thanks for the link and your explanation. Yes, resources and N50 maximisation are definitely factors to consider, though probably not the only one. Using only a single kmer value Trinity may be a bit less greedy in resources, making it attractive to use whereas velvet is known to require lots of RAM, hence my initial question ;-)